# Execute One SQL Block Without Interruption

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

Say I have the following SQL statements that I'm executing using `ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand)` from C# in a Web Application

```
DECLARE @InsertedProductID INT -- this is passed as a parameter
DECLARE @GroupID INT -- this is passed as a parameter
DECLARE @total INT
SET @total = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Products WHERE GroupID = @GroupID)
UPDATE Products SET ProdName = 'Prod_'+ CAST(@total as varchar(15)) 
WHERE ProductID = @InsertedProductID
```

My problem is that I want to ensure that the whole block executes at one. My goal is to always have the `ProdName` unique per group. If I leave everything the way it is, there is a good chance that I will get duplicate product names if an `insert` took place in between getting the `@total` and performing the `UPDATE`. Is there a way to make sure that the whole SQL block executes at once with no interruption. Will `exec` or `sp_executesql` achieve this? My last resort would be to put a `lock` around the `ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand)` But I don't like that since it would create a bottleneck. I don't think that using a sql transaction is helpful here because I'm not worried about the integrity of the commands, I'm rather worried about the parallelism of the commands.

Answer (score 3):

Generally any DML statement (`UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE`) places a lock (row level / table level) on the particular table but if you want to explicitly guarantee that your operation shouldn't interfere with other executing statement then you should consider placing that entire SQL block inside a transaction block saying

```
Begin transaction
begin try
DECLARE @InsertedProductID INT -- this is passed as a parameter
DECLARE @GroupID INT -- this is passed as a parameter
DECLARE @total INT
SET @total = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Products WHERE GroupID = @GroupID)
UPDATE Products SET ProdName = 'Prod_'+ CAST(@total as varchar(15)) WHERE ProductID = @InsertedProductID

commit; // commits the transaction
end try
begin catch
rollback; //Rolls back the transaction
end catch
end
```

You should also consider making the `Transaction Isolation Level` to `READ COMMITTED` to avoid `dirty reads`. Also, obviously you should wrap this entire logic in a `stored procedure` rather executing them as `adhoc SQL`

Answer (score 3):

If you have control of the creation of your SqlConnection objects, consider relying on database locks using [Transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx) and an appropriate [IsolationLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx). Using Snapshot, for example, will cause the second transaction committed to fail if a separate transaction touched the data before the commit occurred.

Something like:

```
var c = new SqlConnection(...);
var tran1 = c.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot);
var tran2 = c.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot);
DoStuff(c, tran1);//Touch some database data
tran1.Commit();
DoStuff(c, tran2);//Change the same data
tran2.Commit();//Error!
```

Answer (score 1):

not so sure you could not just do this

```
UPDATE Products 
SET ProdName = 'Prod_'+ CAST((SELECT COUNT (*) 
                              FROM Products 
                              WHERE GroupID = @GroupID) as varchar(15)) 
WHERE ProductID = @InsertedProductID
```

But to me that is an odd update

Answer (score 1):

Using a transaction is the right way to go. Along with the other answers, you can also use [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx). The [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) implicitly enrolls the connection and SQL command(s) into a transaction. A rollback will happen automatically if there is an issue since the TransactionScope is in a using block.

Example:

```
        try
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand("your SQL here", conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
        {

        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {

        }
```